# How to split a cell 1x1 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, bioinformatics

Let's say I have a 1x1 cell with this value : 'atcatcaaca' .
My goal is :

1. Add 1 to 5 'a' beside any 'a'.
2. Add 1 to 10 'c' beside any 'c'.
3. Add a random number of 'g' beside any 'g'.
4. Add a random number of 't' beside any 't'.

   For example i have 'atcatcaaca'.My goal is to make it like:'aaaattttcccaattttccaaaaaaaaaacccccccccaa'

My thought is to take the value cell and split it somehow in a matrix:
a |   t  | a  | t | c  |a   |a  | c  | a.
Is it possible?And if it is ,how?

The code is :

```
filename = fullfile(matlabroot,'virus_nucleotitde2.dat');

Z = readtable(filename);

S = table2cell(Z);

num_rows = size (Z,1);
num_cols = size (Z,2);
for i=1:1:num_rows
   for j=1:1:num_cols
    B = S(i,j);
    a=0;
    c=0;
    g=0;
    t=0;


B{1} = num2cell(B{1});

n = randi(6);  % Random number between 1 and 6
B{1} = strrep(B{1} , 'a' , repmat('a' , 1, n));

n = randi(11);  % Random number between 1 and 11
B{1} = strrep(B{1} , 'c' , repmat('c' , 1, n));

n = randi(11); 
B{1} = strrep(B{1} , 'g' , repmat('g' , 1, n));

n = randi(11); 
B{1} = strrep(B{1} , 't' , repmat('t' , 1, n));

    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the cell, there is a `char` that you can access with curly brackets:

```
 S = {'ataggatag'};
 B = S{1};
 disp(B)
```

Then, `strrep` is your friend:

```
n = randi(6);  % Random number between 1 and 6
B = strrep(B , 'a' , repmat('a' , 1, n));

n = randi(11);  % Random number between 1 and 11
B = strrep(B , 'c' , repmat('c' , 1, n));

n = randi(11); 
B = strrep(B , 'g' , repmat('g' , 1, n));

n = randi(11); 
B = strrep(B , 't' , repmat('t' , 1, n));
```

Then put it back into the cell

```
S{1} = B;
disp(S)
```

Note that I used 6 as maximum number of 'a's because `strrep` is going to replace the original a, not adding letters beside it as you asked.

EDIT:

Following OP's edit, here is your solution:

```
S = {'ataggatag'};

num_rows = size (S,1);
num_cols = size (S,2);

for i=1:1:num_rows
   for j=1:1:num_cols
        n = randi(6);  % Random number between 1 and 6
        S{i,j} = strrep(S{i,j} , 'a' , repmat('a' , 1, n));

        n = randi(11);  % Random number between 1 and 11
        S{i,j} = strrep(S{i,j} , 'c' , repmat('c' , 1, n));

        n = randi(11); 
        S{i,j} = strrep(S{i,j} , 'g' , repmat('g' , 1, n));

        n = randi(11); 
        S{i,j} = strrep(S{i,j} , 't' , repmat('t' , 1, n));
    end

end

disp(S)
```

Comment: I have done this(look into mu code) and it says: Error using strrep
Cell elements must be character arrays.

Error in bio637 (line 19)
B{1} = strrep(B{1} , 'a' , repmat('a' , 1, n));

Comment: In your modified post, you can replace all B{1} with S{i,j}, and delete B alltogether

Comment: I think it's workingggg but is says with yellow letters:In bio637 (line 18) 
Warning: Inputs must be character arrays or cell arrays of strings.

Comment: Diamadis, I don't know what is on your line 18, nor what is exactly into your S or Z variables, so I really cannot help you there!

Comment: Iam reading a file from virus_nucleotitde2.dat.Im reading this as a table and convert it to cell as.The virus_nucleotide2.dat has 'gtacagac' 'ctgaagtc'............It has many sequences.But thank you its okay i solved my problem.But i have another question.I have a txt with a big sequence of characters.'BGATTTTAACCGAGAGATGAG.........BGATT'.There are 700 characters.How i can import them to 700 seperate cells?

Comment: A quick google search gives [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/109411-split-string-into-3-letter-each).

b = cellstr(reshape(S{i,j} , 1 , []))

Answer (score 0):

It's already so.. `'a string'` is an array of chars, so in order to convert them to a cell array you need to use the usual `num2cell` function:

```
>> name_in_1x1_cell_array{1} = 'ataggatag'

name_in_1x1_cell_array = 

    'ataggatag'

>> name_in_1x1_cell_array{1} = num2cell(name_in_1x1_cell_array{1})

name_in_1x1_cell_array = 

    {1x9 cell}
```

You can also access to characters directly, for example you can cycle every character of a string and display it:

```
name = 'some name';
for i = 1 : length(name)
  disp(name(i));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, not the code:

With the function `strrep` this is straightforward, as it operates on cell arrays as well:

```
cell_string = {'atcatcaaca'};

% add a's
cell_string = strrep(cell_string, 'a', repmat('a',1,5));

% add c's
cell_string = strrep(cell_string, 'c', repmat('c',1,10));

% add t's
cell_string = strrep(cell_string, 't', repmat('t',1,randi(10)));
```

The function `repmat` is used to duplicate characters.